# Arrange % in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking for some help with two small problems I have. I have made a small stock portfolio spreadsheet, which the link is: [Link to spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rKudPNj8-MgQNB5kpX56J-c40C5d0OqZRzVyaecBTWo/edit?usp=sharing)
I am trying to show the gap difference in % of stocks in real time using google finance. Column’s 6 -10, are the correct %, but showing up as a -%. Is there any way to show the % without the -?

In addition, how can I sort the spreadsheet to show lowest % at the top, highest at the bottom?
For example, I would like the spreadsheet to show:

> FL 49.98 50.33 short 0.70%
>
> MDZL 43.22 42.50 long 1.67%
>
> STX 38.20 37.44 long 1.99%
>
> WR 53.13 54.47 short 2.52%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort, select columns A-F. Select Data from the menu. From the dropdown select Sort Range. Click Data has header row. In Sort by, select column F, A-Z. Click Sort. That should do it. I don't understand "Is there any way to show the % without the -?"